# Script variables not printing as expected

Tags: bash-scripting

In an attempt to debug a script, I'm printing variables containing text, pretty standard stuff, except that the variables are not behaving as expected. I've discovered that one of the lines of a file I'm reading in, is less than 17 characters long, messing up the script further on, so I'm testing for less than a length of 17 and trying to add 18 spaces. What happens is that the spaces are being added to the start of the variable and overwriting the letters there, not at the end where I expect them to be added. The length calculation shows correctly at 35 though.

```
do STR=$line  
length=${#STR}  
spaces=".                ." <<<<18 spaces in here  
end=end   
if [ $length -le 17 ]  
then  
TEMPSTR=$STR  
echo $TEMPSTR  
echo $end  
echo $length  
TEMPSTR2="$TEMPSTR$spaces"  
length=${#TEMPSTR2}  
echo $TEMPSTR2  
echo $length  
fi
```

is reading in a line "Fan Tray(8 spaces)" producing:

```
Fan Tray  
end  
17  
.                . <<< 18 spaces in here  
35
```

I'm expecting it to show:

```
Fan Tray  
end  
17  
Fan Tray.                . <<< 18 spaces in here  
35
```

Comment: are you trying to do space padding ?

Comment: Well I suppose ultimately, yes. I want to add spaces to make the original variable longer. This is so that later in the script when I use:                                                     'SpItem=$(echo "$STR" | cut -c1-17)'   'SpItem="${SpItem##*( )}"' it will cut the item correctly and delete the tailing spaces correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing IFS.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=%
STR="Fan Tray         "
length=${#STR}
spaces=".                ."
end=end
    if [ $length -le 17 ]
    then
    TEMPSTR=$STR
    echo $TEMPSTR  
    echo $spaces
    echo $end  
    echo $length  
    TEMPSTR2="$TEMPSTR$spaces"
    length=${#TEMPSTR2}
    echo $TEMPSTR2  
    echo $length  
fi
unset IFS
```

After running the output was

```
Fan Tray         
.                .
end
17
Fan Tray         .                .
35
```

Comment: I already have IFS="," set earlier in the script.

Comment: I've tried it set to IFS="%" and it makes no difference. The output is the same. If I create the above in a stand-alone script it works as expected, so the original script must be affecting it in someway. Should I post the whole thing?

Comment: What happens if you hardcode STR="Fan Tray"?

Comment: If I hardcode STR="Fan Tray" it works:                                                            Fan Tray
end
8
Fan Tray.                .
26

Comment: I did wonder if the line being read contained a non-printable character, like a Carraige Return, but I used cat -vet filename and the line is the same as all the others, just much shorter, and ends ^M$.

Comment: Final suggestion. Change the concat to TEMPSTR2="$TEMPSTR.               ."

Comment: Actually that was the first thing I tried :-( Thank you very much for trying to help though, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

EUREEKA!

The variable was including the ^M Carraige Return character on it's end, so adding spaces to it meant it would print the spaces *after* executing the Carraige Return, after it had printed the words "Fan Tray", thereby overwriting the words "Fan Tray" but leaving the variable length correct.
I stripped off the Carraige Return *before* adding the spaces and BINGO!!. Thus:

```
while read line  
do STR=$line  
length=${#STR}  
spaces="                  "  
if [ $length -le 17 ]  
then  
TEMPSTR=$(echo $STR | tr -d '\r')  
STR="$TEMPSTR$spaces"  
fi
```